# Unwind functionality with underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I need mongodb's `$unwind` like functionality with underscore, so that

```
[{
    groups: [{ name: 'test 1' }, { name: 'test 2' }],
    id: 1
}]
```

became

```
[{
    id: 1,
    group: {
        name: 'test 1'
    }
}, {
    id: 1,
    group: {
        name: 'test 2'
    }
}]
```

Can this be done with underscore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can map a new object for each element in the target field. For example, with a mixin and assuming you want a method signature looking like `_.unwind(object, field)` :

```
_.mixin({
    unwind: function(o, field) {
        return _.map(o[field], function(val) {
            var cloned = _.clone(o);
            cloned[field] = val;
            return cloned;
        });
    }
});
```

You would use it like this :

```
_.unwind({
    groups: [{ name: 'test 1' }, { name: 'test 2' }],
    id: 1
}, 'groups');
```

And

- a Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/ag31ypeb/
- a snippet

```js
function log(obj) {
  document.getElementById('logged').innerHTML+= '<p>'+JSON.stringify(obj)+'</p>';
}

_.mixin({
    unwind: function(o, field) {
        return _.map(o[field], function(val) {
            var cloned = _.clone(o);
            cloned[field] = val;
            return cloned;
        });
    }
});

var o = { _id : 1, item : "ABC1", sizes: [ "S", "M", "L"] };
log(_.unwind(o, 'sizes'));

var g = {
    groups: [{ name: 'test 1' }, { name: 'test 2' }],
    id: 1
};
log(_.unwind(g, 'groups'));
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"></script>

<div id='logged'></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need unwind an array of objects (more like mongodb's unwind) you can use this function:

```
function unwindBy(arr, field){
  return _.transform(arr, function(r, o){ 
    Array.prototype.push.apply(r, 
      _.map(o[field], function(v){ return _.set(_.clone(o), field, v); })
    );
  }, []);
}
```

ES6 allows rewrite it much shorter and with no dependencies to 3rd party libs:

```
function unwindBy(arr, f) {
  return arr.reduce((r, o) => r.concat(o[f].map(v => ({ ...o, [f]: v }))), []);
}
```

Example:

```
unwindBy([{a:1, b:[1,2,3]}, {a:2, b:[3,4,5]}], 'b');
//[{a:1, b:1}, {a:1, b:2}, {a:1, b:3}, {a:2, b:3}, {a:2, b:4}, {a:2, b:5}]
```

Comment: Love this, used it as a one-liner myself:
`const unWindBy = (a, f) => a.reduce((r, o) => r.concat(o[f].map(v => ({ ...o, [f]: v }))), []);`

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to add the destination field, you can do it using the below snippet. It is a modification based on @nikoshr's answer.

```js
function log(obj) {
  document.getElementById('logged').innerHTML+= '<p>'+JSON.stringify(obj)+'</p>';
}

_.mixin({
    unwind: function(o, field, toField) {
        if(!toField) toField = field;
        return _.map(o[field], function(val) {
            var cloned = _.clone(o);
            cloned[toField] = val;
            return cloned;
        });
    }
});

var o = { _id : 1, item : "ABC1", sizes: [ "S", "M", "L"] };
log(_.unwind(o, 'sizes'));

var g = {
    groups: [{ name: 'test 1' }, { name: 'test 2' }],
    id: 1
};
log(_.unwind(g, 'groups', 'group'));
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.5.2/underscore-min.js"></script>

<div id='logged'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> This function will help to unwind a json object.

```
function flatten()
{
    var objectData = [];
    var arrayData = [];
    var arrayDataKey = [];
    var resultSet = [];

    this.progress = function(doc){
        objectData = [this.getObjectData(doc)];
        this.unwindData(objectData,arrayData);
        return resultSet;
    }

    this.getObjectData = function(doc,keyId){ 
        var result = {};
        var index = '';
        if(keyId=='' || keyId==undefined){
            keyId = '';
        }

        for(key in doc){
            if(keyId==''){
                index = key;
            }else{    
                index =  keyId+'.'+key;
            }

            if(Array.isArray(doc[key])===true){
                if(typeof doc[key][0]=="object"){
                    arrayDataKey.push(key);
                    arrayData.push(doc[key]);
                }else{
                    result[index] = doc[key];
                }
            }else if(typeof doc[key]=="object"){
                if(doc[key]=="[object Object]"){
                    for (var k in data = this.getObjectData(doc[key],index)) { result[k] = data[k]; }
                }else{

                    result[index] = doc[key];
                }
            }else{
                result[index] = doc[key];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    this.unwindData = function(doc,objectData){
        for (var i = objectData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            resultSet = [];
            for(var key in doc){
                for (var prop in objectData[i]) {
                    objectData[i][prop] = this.getObjectData(objectData[i][prop]);
                    for(var k in objectData[i][prop]){
                        var ke = arrayDataKey[i]+'.'+k;
                        doc[key][ke] = objectData[i][prop][k];
                    }
                    resultSet.push(doc[key]);
                }
            }
            doc  = resultSet;
        }
    }
}
```

var flat = new flatten();
flat.progress();

Answer (score 0):

You can check out [lodash-unwind](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash-unwind)

Sample usage:

```
const _ = require('lodash')
require('lodash-unwind')({ injected: true })
const data = [
{
    a: [ 1, 2 ],
    id: 'a1'
},
{
    a: [ 3, 4 ],
    id: 'a2'
}]
// Use unwind as part of lodash
const output = _.unwind(data, 'a')
// [
//   {
//     a: 1,
//     id: 'a1'
//   },
//   {
//     a: 2,
//     id: 'a1'
//   },
//   {
//     a: 3,
//     id: 'a2'
//   },
//   {
//     a: 4,
//     id: 'a2'
//   }
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use npm package [unwind-array](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unwind-array) see some [example usages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unwind-array#ex1-unwind-shallow-path).

Answer (score 0):

There is npm package [unwind-array](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unwind-array) that you can try.

```
const { unwind } = require('unwind-array')
const result = unwind(
  {
    title: 'foobar',
    topLevelArr: [1, 2]
  },
  { path: 'topLevelArr' }
)
expect(result.length).to.be.equal(2)
expect(result).to.be.deep.equal([
  {
    title: 'foobar',
    topLevelArr: 1
  },
  {
    title: 'foobar',
    topLevelArr: 2
  }
])
```